# how to make an image appear full as image background

Tags: php, html, css

the code below displays the image multiple time like into 10 different image, need it to be full image..

```
<HTML>

<BODY >

<style>
body {background-image:url('back1.jpg');}
</style>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this has always worked for me.

```
body {
    background: url(cool-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover; 
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<HTML>

<BODY >

<style>
body {background-image:url('back1.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;} // add the no repeat 
</style>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: it appears in the top left, need it to be full

Answer (score 0):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```